# Recreating cyclic autocorrelation plot for Zadoff-Chu in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, signal-processing

I'm trying to get a better grip of how it all flows and I'm trying to plot myself a Dirac delta plot which is supposed to be an effect of putting a Zadoff-Chu through cyclic autocorrelation.

This is the formula that I'm adhering to:

```
circcorr_ab = ifft(fft(a).*conj(fft(b)))
```

And I'm expecting something resembling this (zeroes on Y besides X = 0)

[image: this]

Instead I'm getting this:

[image: this]

Obviously I'm getting very small values on Y axis, zeros for all intents and purposes, and an expected 839 on the X axis. It looks like I need to flip the plot and normalize the values but I can't come up with a functioning solution.

Help appreciated.

Comment: How are you creating the plot?

Comment: Straight _plot(circorr_ab)_

Comment: Try `plot(abs(...))`

Comment: Jeebus, of course it worked. I've played around with abs() and was completely sure I've tried all the options. I must have put it on when other things were already changed in the formula. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to plot the absolute value of the result.  Try

```
plot(abs(circcorr_ab))
```